# More efficient way to iterate groupby Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have this snippet code that groupby column `ID` from a pandas dataframe and appends in a result dataframe all the top salaries from a unique ID. The code works but is kind of slow with larger files. I was wondering if someone could suggest a more efficient way.

```
groupe = df.groupby("ID")
t = (group.sort_values(by="Salary", ascending=False)[:1] for yr, group in groupe)
result = pd.DataFrame() 
     for i in t:
        result = result.append(i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.groupby('ID').max()
```

You can then select the salaries column.

**Edit**

If you want to retain all other columns, even the non-numerical, this should do the job:

```
df.sort_values(by="Salary", ascending=False).groupby('ID').first()
```

Comment: if I have other columns, how would it know to max my Salary column. Also I seem to be loosing columns that have non-null rows. I need to keep these in the dataframe.

Comment: Take a look at the edit. Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: getting an error that DataFrameGroupBy objecy has no attribute "top" but I think head(1) works instead

Comment: Try .first()  sorry, I'm on mobile, can't test it

Comment: Yes, first() should work, I looked at the docs now. I changed the answer

Comment: Glad to help. Please select the answer :)

Comment: not sure how but I think I need more pts to be able to. Will make sure to select answer when I get there.